# How to use assert in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, assert

I am trying to learn OCaml and I am having trouble with the assertion statement. In the interpreter I can use it:

```
Zameers-MacBook-Air:~ zmanji$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let x = 1;;
val x : int = 1
# assert(x > 2);;
Exception: Assert_failure ("//toplevel//", 1, 0).
# ^D
```

However when I put the code in a file that looks like this:

```
let x = 1
assert(x > 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Zameers-MacBook-Air:Q4 zmanji$ ocaml test.ml
File "test.ml", line 2, characters 0-6:
Error: Syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you put the `;;` in the file it will work. Without that, it doesn't make sense syntactically. An expression `1` followed by the keyword `assert` doesn't make sense.

I don't particularly like using `;;` in actual code (not at top-level, i.e., the interpreter). If you wanted to avoid it too, you could write

```
let x = 1
let () = assert (x > 2)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Does Ocaml read the expression and continue to `assert`? Is there somewhere I can read more about how OCaml delimits statements?