# Assert not triggering

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a recursive power function in OCaml, and I'm trying to add an assert to ensure the exponent is always greater than or equal to 0.

My code is

```
let rec power (x:int) (n:int) : int =
  assert (n >= 0)
  if n==0 then 1
  else x * (power x (n - 1))
```

This gives me a syntax error in the `if`. I've tried

```
let rec power (x:int) (n:int) : int =
  let () = assert (n >= 0) in 
    if n==0 then 1
    else x * (power x (n - 1))
```

(similar to what is shown in [How to use assert in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567318/how-to-use-assert-in-ocaml)) but the `assert` never triggers.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Note that I *do* want to use `assert`, not `failwith`, mostly as a matter of learning.

Comment: You forgot a semicolon: assert (n >= 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is fine. Most likely the problem was in the way you tested it.

Here's a session that shows how it works:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let rec power (x:int) (n:int) : int =
  let () = assert (n >= 0) in 
    if n==0 then 1
    else x * (power x (n - 1))      ;;
val power : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# power 3 (-2);;
Exception: Assert_failure ("//toplevel//", 2, 11).
#
```

**Update**

As camlspotter points out, your first example is also fine if you add a semicolon between the assert and the rest:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let rec power (x:int) (n:int) : int =
  assert (n >= 0);  (* <--  Semicolon here *)
    if n==0 then 1
  else x * (power x (n - 1))
    ;;
val power : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# power 2 3;;
- : int = 8
# power 2 (-3);;
Exception: Assert_failure ("//toplevel//", 2, 2).
```

Answer (score 1):

The first code fogot to put `;` after `assert (n >= 0)`. It should be triggered when `n < 0`.

BTW,

What's funny here is that `assert` is not a function and its application to too many arguments does not cause a type error but a syntax error which may be hard to understand for beginners.

`failwith` is a function and the same mistake is reported more nicely (but as a warning):

```
# failwith;;
- : string -> 'a = <fun>
# failwith "hello" 1;;
Characters 17-18:
Warning 20: this argument will not be used by the funciton.
```

`assert` is not a function but a keyword with less kind error messages:

```
# assert;;
        ^^
Error: Syntax error
# assert true true;;
              ^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

The reason `assert` is not a normal function of type `bool -> unit` is not sure but I guess it is for `assert false` which is treated specially and compiled to raise an assertion failure immediately without looking at the argument.

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be `assert false` being treated specially as well since, when no-assert is on, those particular asserts are actually preserved.