# assert in one standalone ocaml program

Tags: ocaml, assertion

Having read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567318/how-to-use-assert-in-ocaml) , I put this code into my `.ml` file:

```ml
let x = [3;5;9]
(* Testing append to the list *)
let () = assert( x @ [2;10] == [3;5;9;2;10])
```

And run

```
$ ocamlc -o BasicList BasicList.ml  && ./BasicList 
Fatal error: exception Assert_failure("BasicList.ml", 3, 9)
```

- Why this error occurs?
- Is there another effective or good-practice way to test my functions? Most textbooks I read only demonstrate in the REPL tho. I'm new to Ocaml so it would great to hear from your exprience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/index.html) of Ocaml.

In recent [`Stdlib`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/libref/Stdlib.html), you probably want to use the `=` structural equality operator  and code

```
 assert( x @ [2;10] = [3;5;9;2;10])
```

Notice that `==`  is coding the *physical equality* operator (of "pointers", more precisely of physical boxed values).

> ```
> val (==) : 'a -> 'a -> bool
> ```
>
> `e1 == e2` tests for physical equality of e1 and e2. On mutable types
>   such as references, arrays, byte sequences, records with mutable
>   fields and objects with mutable instance variables, e1 == e2 is true
>   if and only if physical modification of e1 also affects e2. *On
>   non-mutable types, the behavior of `( == )` is implementation-dependent;*
>   however, it is guaranteed that e1 == e2 implies compare e1 e2 = 0.
>   Left-associative operator, see `Ocaml_operators` for more information.

BTW, the `ocaml`  programming language [has](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10.0.html) an [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) implementation. You should consider studying its source code.

Be aware that comparing with `=` two long lists of length *n* has a [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of *O(n)*. But `==`  is constant time. For lists of many thousands of elements that makes a difference.

As an exercise, code the equivalent of `=` for lists (e.g. using just a `letrec`, `match` and `==`).